# Calculate variance, quartiles in Weka explorer

Tags: weka

I am using Weka for Data mining a dataset. I can find median, stdev using explorer but not range, quartiles, variance and mode. Is there any configuration required in the tool for the same or it just can't possible with the tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Filter, the Unsupervised Attribute Filter "AddExpression" or the "MathExpression", to calculate something for a single attribute.

Obviously, this is primitive, and you cannot do this for each attribute in one fell swoop.